# Slim - Swift Mailer on the route is work but if after moved on controller get errors

Tags: php, slim, swiftmailer, fortrabbit

I add libraries slimcontroller and swift mailer in my slim project, 
when in route goes well:

```
Route::get('/send', function() use ($app, $mailer) {

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Activation Code')
                ->setFrom(array('xxx@gmail.com' => 'xxx'))
                ->setTo(array('xxxs@gmail.com' => 'xxxs'))
                ->setBody('Test');

// Send the message
$results = $mailer->send($message);

// Print the results, 1 = message sent!
print($results);
});
```

but after a run on the controller there is an error

```
class MyController extends \SlimController\SlimController
{

    public function getRegisters()
    {
        $data = (empty(\Session::flash())) ? array(
            'token' => \Token::getToken()
        ) : array_merge(\Session::flash(), array(
            'token' => \Token::getToken()
        ));

        return $this->render('auth/register.html', $data);
    }
    public function postRegisters()
    {
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Activation Code')->setFrom(array(
            'xxx@gmail.com' => 'xxx'
        ))->setTo(array(
            'xxxs@gmail.com' => 'xxxs'
        ))->setBody('Test');

        // Send the message
        $results = $this->app->mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

**Fatal error: Call to a member function send() on a non-object in.**

I reference from [fortrabbit/slimcontroller](https://github.com/fortrabbit/slimcontroller#controller-2)

Comment: At some point you must do `$app->mailer = $mailer` for your code to work.

Comment: @Mika. if this code place in the route is work but if place in the controllers is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing here (since I don' have your full Controller code) that your controller's `$this->app` is empty. Slim won't inject the `$app` object in your controllers.

There are several ways to inject dependencies with Slim. I'm not entirely sure what's the best practice here. But I'd start [looking here](https://github.com/akrabat/rka-slim-controller).

Also, you can do some nasty hack in your controllers `__construct`. Although I don't recommend it, it would look something like:

```
class Controller {
    protected $app;
    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    }
}
```

If you are sure that your controller have the `$app` property, then the problem is how you inject your `$mailer` instance. As I see from your routes, you're passing both the `$app` and the `$mailer` to the closure.

You can [inject that mailer object into your app as a singleton](http://docs.slimframework.com/di/overview/). The code should be something like:

```php
$app->mailer = function() {
   $mailer = new WhateverMailerYouAreUsing();
   // ...config stuff...

   return $mailer;
};
```

Comment: hai, @fedeisas. I have updated the controller. The object slimcontroller <pre>$app</pre> has been automatically injecting in controllers.

Comment: @Defri I have updated my answer to explain how to inject `$mailer` object into your app, and a link to the Slim DI docs. Have fun!

Comment: thanks for reference use Slim DI. yeah .. I have successfully used swiftmailer in my controller. This document swiftmailer configuration in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/defriblackertz/b921af501e206f0a476a). Thank you for the help.